# How to get same Localized results from Google CSE Json API

Tags: api, google-custom-search

i am using the Google CSE Json API in order to receive results on generic queries from Google.
I have configured the Google Engine to return results from all web sites.
i though that this setting would make me use Google as if i was using it from the Google web site via the regular search engine.
BUT - i don't get same results that i would have expected to get from the site. i have major differences and i was wondering why.
From the past reading that i have made, i know that the API uses a certain server(s) around UK, making the results not the same due to the locale settings.
i have read the documentation on the CSE site and saw that there are 2 parameters that i thought would have improved the state:

1. googlehost - specifying the domain to use. this parameter is deprecated according to the documentation, hence i used the second parameter
2. gl - specify a country code for the search

both parameters didn't affect my results at all.
i am struggling with this for quite a long time and would appreciate a proper solution for it.
all i want is to have a CSE that acts the same as the google website. Running a search here and there should not differ in the returned results.

your help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
attiass

Comment: Do you have some examples of searches that don't behave as you'd expect?

Comment: Yes i do. Searching for the value "061247890" in Google and in the CSE site, end up with different results. There's at least 1 result missing from a site called OLX-ba. It's pretty simple to reproduce it, just need to find a result that does not bring up tons of results. If you have any idea, please share.

Comment: Does anyone have any issue like mine? The #Google team might assist here..?

Comment: If you want a hard restrict to a specific country you can try using the 'cr' parameter described on this page: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list

CSE search in general does not guarantee the same comprehensiveness as Google Web Search.

Comment: Irrelevant. Any other idea?